# Простой индикатор прогресса населения стран,- статический или анимированный

Tags: javascript, html, css, css3, svg

Мне нужно сделать простой индикатор прогресса бара населения стран.

Мне  нужен бар с зеленой полосой прогресса для хорошего количества и еще одна цветная часть для плохой суммы, а количество в процентах, где-то посередине бара.

Предположим, что полоса имеет ширину 50 пикселей и высоту 15 пикселей. Подумайте о статическом индикаторе выполнения, как показано ниже.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Я сделал это перед использованием `jquery` и фонового `div` с двумя дополнительными `div`, расположенными поверх него для хороших и плохих индикаторов, а затем позиционированным `div` над ним для отображения текста.

Однако мне интересно, есть ли еще более простой решение с `HTML5-canvas`, `SVG` или `CSS`. 
Поскольку этот тайм-контроль будет отображаться в каждом ряду длинной таблицы, цель состоит в том, чтобы уменьшить `DOM`, повысить читаемость и повторное использование.
Я знаю, что есть библиотеки, которые это делают, но я хотел использовать его в качестве учебного опыта. Решение должно быть либо не скриптом, либо только JS, либо JS с jquery.

Мой макет

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: ассоциация:https://stackoverflow.com/q/44594366/7394871

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Вот выполнение с помощью SVG вашего макета:

```js
$("svg.tbc").each(function(i, item) {
  var $item = $(item);
  var rate = $item.parent().find(".country").attr("rate");
  $item.find(".bar").attr("width", rate);
  $item.find("text").text(rate);
});
```

```css
.tbc {
  width: 50px;
  height: 15px;
}

.tbc .bg {
  fill: gold;  
  fill-opacity: 0.5;
}

.tbc .bar {
  fill: blue;
  fill-opacity: 0.5;
}

.tbc text {
  font-size: 8pt;
  font-family: Calibri, sans-serif;
  font-weight: bold;
  fill: blue;
}

.country {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 200px;
}

.info {
  margin-top: 20;
  font-size: 10px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<h1>Urban population rate by country </h1>

<div>
  <div class="country" rate="57.6%">China</div>
  <svg class="tbc"><rect class="bg" width="100%" height="100%"/><rect class="bar" width="0%" height="100%"/><text x="50%" y="70%" text-anchor="middle">0%</text></svg>
</div>

<div>
  <div class="country" rate="32%">India</div>
  <svg class="tbc"><rect class="bg" width="100%" height="100%"/><rect class="bar" width="0%" height="100%"/><text x="50%" y="70%" text-anchor="middle">0%</text></svg>
</div>

<div>
  <div class="country" rate="82.1%">U.S.</div>
  <svg class="tbc"><rect class="bg" width="100%" height="100%"/><rect class="bar" width="0%" height="100%"/><text x="50%" y="70%" text-anchor="middle">0%</text></svg>
</div>

<div>
  <div class="country" rate="73.2%">Russia</div>
  <svg class="tbc"><rect class="bg" width="100%" height="100%"/><rect class="bar" width="0%" height="100%"/><text x="50%" y="70%" text-anchor="middle">0%</text></svg>
</div>

<div>
  <div class="country" rate="81.2%">UK</div>
  <svg class="tbc"><rect class="bg" width="100%" height="100%"/><rect class="bar" width="0%" height="100%"/><text x="50%" y="70%" text-anchor="middle">0%</text></svg>
</div>

<div>
  <div class="country" rate="11.5%">Burundi</div>
  <svg class="tbc"><rect class="bg" width="100%" height="100%"/><rect class="bar" width="0%" height="100%"/><text x="50%" y="70%" text-anchor="middle">0%</text></svg>
</div>

<div class="info"><a href="http://www.worldometers.info/world-population/population-by-country/" target="">Source: www.worldometers.info/</a>
```